# Printing a Grid of cells in erlang

Tags: printing, erlang

I'm new to erlang and programming in general.

I want to create a "Grid" of cells, where a cell is presented as:

```
+   +

+   +
```

What I know is the width and the height of the Grid.

So, for example, a 3x3 Grid is represented as:

```
+  +  +  + 

+  +  +  +

+  +  +  +

+  +  +  +
```

`print_grid(Height,Width)` ->
    and than some code here.

Can someone maybe give me a tip on how to solve this?

Comment: Not quite sure what the downvotes are for. OP is *new to programming* so its not impossible that the function head is as far as he's able to go on solving this alone.

Comment: There are plenty of guides on how to start with programming. This "question" is more of a "give me the code, please" situation which didn't involve any effort on OPs part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you may use this function

```
grid(_,0)->ok;

grid(W,H)->
    io:format(string:copies("+   ",W-1)++"+~n~n"),
    grid(W,H-1).
```

output:

```
sol:grid(6,3).
+   +   +   +   +   +

+   +   +   +   +   +

+   +   +   +   +   +



15> sol:grid(3,3).
+   +   +

+   +   +

+   +   +
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you do not need other feature like adding some characters in the cells, but you should be able to modify this:

```
4> Pgrid= fun(W,H) -> L = lists:foldl(fun(_,Acc) -> "+   " ++ Acc end,"~n~n",lists:seq(1,W+1)),
4>        G = lists:foldl(fun(_,Acc)-> L ++ Acc end,[],lists:seq(1,H+1)), 
4>        io:format(G)                                                                                
4>        end.                                                                                        
#Fun<erl_eval.12.54118792>
5> Pgrid(6,3).                                                                                 
+   +   +   +   +   +   +   

+   +   +   +   +   +   +   

+   +   +   +   +   +   +   

+   +   +   +   +   +   +   

ok
6>
```